# Updating Firebase when user closes/exits Expo app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

How can I make it such that when the user exits/closes the expo app, it updates the my realtime database? I can make it work when the user clicks on the logout button explicitly but I am not sure how to handle the scenario when a user just closes the app.

Comment: Could you please add what you tried? Code example will be good

Answer (score 0):

Use *[BackHandler](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler)* to detect when the user presses the back button.
Then depending on your use case,

- Either you can show the user some kind of label like *"wait for
  synchronization"* and send your data to the server (**Note:** This isn't a good User experience)
- Or you can schedule a background job when user exits the app and the background job handles your data syncrhonization. (**Note:** There doesn't seem to have any **official** option for background tasks in React Native.)

The choice stays up to you and your use case.